# dkan dataset not displaying drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, dkan

Here is what is going on.

I have Drupal 7 setup and I'm using the dkan module. What seems to be going on is that every time I click on a item (for example I click on an item like this: http://sitename/?q=dataset/dataset-name), but I get title of the dataset and the following error message: The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

So I check the log and I'm seeing the following message:

Location http://sitename/?q=dataset/dataset-name Referrer sitename/?q=search/type/dataset Message EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unknown data property field_modified_source_date. in EntityStructureWrapper->getPropertyInfo() (line 354 of /var/www/html/site/profiles/dkan/modules/contrib/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc).

What could be causing the issue and how would I go about resolving it?

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have a problem with `clean_urls`.

When you're logged into your DKAN instance go to **Configuration** > **Search and metadata** > **Clean URLs**.

Check **Enable clean URLs** and click **Save Configuration**.